# Extended survey database design with rules

Tags: database-design

I have looked at many of the survey questions posted and can't find what I am looking for...hoping someone can help.

I am trying to include in the database schema a way to provide navigation and conditional paths for questions.

Basically the "if Other is selected please complete the text box with the details" or "if yes, please answer this next question" - the RULES for completing the survey/questionnaire.

How would you implement that criteria into a normal survey/questionnaire schema?

Answer (score 0):

How about a transition table that is examined after the question is answered:

```
transition_id int
question_id int
answer_id int / answer_value varchar
next_question_id int
```

So after I answer "other" to question 5, you query this table to determine the next_question_id.

You can add multiple transition and have a default (when answer_id IS NULL, perhaps?).